# How to properly use fontawesome on React js?

Tags: reactjs

First I install fontawesome and import it like this.

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

I find my icon and code for react

but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

As written in [font awesome documentation](https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/use-with/react), you can easily use it like this:

First, install the package by:

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
  // Light:
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fal", "coffee"]} />
  // Regular:
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["far", "coffee"]} />
  // Solid
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fas", "coffee"]} />
  // ...or, omit as FontAwesome defaults to solid, so no need to prefix:
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon="coffee" />
  // Brand:
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fab", "github"]} />
```

You can also use it like this:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const element = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
```

Sizing:

```
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon="coffee" size="xs" />
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon="coffee" size="lg" />
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon="coffee" size="6x" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this;

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
```

You have to import icon.
You can see detailed usage on [docs](https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/use-with/react).